# c++ Static variables in dynamic DLL lifetime. or why they dead?

Tags: c++, windows

so, I load Dll with some global static variables(loggers). and there is no freelibrary. on close application I call methods from dll but global static variables already destroyed. why???

Comment: When exactly do you call those methods?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean? What are these static variables, how do you initialize them, do you assign anything to them from the application, etc.

Comment: Avoid static objects in DLL unless they are DllMain-safe. For example objects containing FILE* or std::fstream are *NOT* DllMain-safe. See recent thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114683/loading-dll-not-initializing-static-c-classes/5115008#5115008 and this article http://go.microsoft.com/FWLink/?LinkId=84138

Answer (score 2):

The static variables in the DLL will be destroyed when the DLL is unloaded. This will happen when the process exits, before the static variables from the main EXE are destroyed, if there is no explicit `FreeLibrary` call to make it happen earlier.

Comment: `static bool Loggable;
class Flag{
public:
 bool &live_detector_;
 Flag(bool &live_detector):live_detector_(live_detector){
  live_detector_ = true;
 }
 ~Flag(){
  live_detector_ = false;
 }

};

Flag f(Loggable);`???