# Initalization of static structure in C++

Tags: c++, singleton, static-members

I'm implementing a thread safe singleton class in C++.
I need a way of initializing the mutex which guards the `getInstance()` method.

This is a self contained shared library, so I can't use a mutex from another class, I have to find a way to initialize it inside the class.

The library has to be ported to various platforms, so let's consider that the mutex is:

```
static void * OS_mutex;
```

and to initialize it you use

`OS_Mutex_Init ( void * mutex);`

I tried to implement a nested class which in it's constructor I initialize the OS_mutex structure.

but I ran into some troubles, Does anyone knows a way to achieve what I need ?
Any references, or links will be much appreciated.

Comment: Quite curious what kind of troubles did you get?

Comment: So, what's the problem exactly? Are you trying to target some ancient platform that doesn't just do thread-safe initialisation of static members for you?

Comment: @NicholasWilson This solution has to work within Linux, Android (bionic lib), Windows 8, etc. I can't make any assumption regarding the implementation of mutex's.

Comment: If you -1, provide a comment !

Comment: @Mellowcandle I got that; the question is, what makes you think your static initialisers aren't already thread-safe? Surely they are even on bionic, because it's so cheap for the compiler just to bang in a test-and-set for you (ARM and x86 are the fast platforms).

Answer (score 0):

First, declare it as a variable:

```
static MyStruct OS_Mutex;
```

Where:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    void* pointer;
    MyStruct() : pointer(0)
    {
        // Called on initialization of global variables by the CRT

        // You can call here your function OS_Mutex_Init()
        // Or you can use lazy initialization (leave the pointer to 0,
        // and initialize it only when someone needs it)
    }
};
```

Then, these two answers might help you:

- [Loading DLL not initializing static classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114683/loading-dll-not-initializing-static-c-classes)
- [What happens to global variables declared in a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701/what-happens-to-global-variables-declared-in-a-dll)